# how to know about the tag value from the view

Tags: iphone, uiview, tags

I am making an App in which i have a view where i am showing friends details.
So, If i need to change the details. I will have to check on the label to change it.
Here,I have set tag value for each label.

If the user presses a label the new text field will appear on the view and the user can change the Details.

So for this i have written touch began method in which i am checking the touch value...
But whenever i am touching any label i am getting the tag value of view as zero where as i should get the tag value of the label on wich i have clicked .

My code is shown below...

```
txtTmp = [[UITextField alloc] init];    

//txtTmp is the textfield which should appear as super view of the label where i have clicked

    txtTmp.delegate=self;

self.lblName.tag=11;

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
```

//here i am getting the tag value as 0 even if i have enabled the user interaction...

```
NSLog(@"view.tag = %d",touch.view.tag);

if(touch.view.tag==11) {



    [txtTmp setFrame:CGRectMake(162, 43, 138, 50)];
    txtTmp.text=lblName.text;
    [self.view addSubview:txtTmp];
    [txtTmp becomeFirstResponder];
    temp=1;



}
```

If u have any problem regarding my question..Please get back to me....

Thanks,

Comment: are you set the tag value for label?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should enable user interaction of self.lblName.

```
   [self.lblName setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Also you can check for touched label in touchesbegan method using viewWithTag message:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

if(touch.view == [self.view viewWithTag:11]) 
{
    [txtTmp setFrame:CGRectMake(162, 43, 138, 50)];
    txtTmp.text=lblName.text;
    [self.view addSubview:txtTmp];
    [txtTmp becomeFirstResponder];
    temp=1;
}
```

Comment: @Thanks,,For the answer..After asking the question..I did the samething Ma'am....Thanks,once again.